# Randrange outcome help? Python Random Number Generator

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator

Trying to create a Random Number Generator that depending on the number outputs a statement. I keep getting the output of Over 50 no matter what. I can't seem to figure out why though.

```
from random import randrange
print randrange(100)

number = randrange

if number <= 49:
    print"Under 50"
else:
    print"Over 50"
```

Changing the following line corrected the issue.

```
number = randrange(100)
```

Comment: What do you think `number = randrange` does exactly?

Comment: print `number` to screen and go from there.

Comment: I was thinking that number would take the number from  randrange outut. I feel that it's not actually pulling a number from that at all though.

Comment: You're right, it's not. You need to do what you did in the `print`, `number = randrange(100)`. If you used Python 3 you would have gotten an error.

Comment: Thanks a ton when I printed number I saw it wasn't pulling anything. I have it working now! I didn't know how to define randranges output working now thank you hopefully I can build off of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement doesn't do what you think:

```
number = randrange
```

It's setting `number` to the function, not to a result from calling the function. If you now did `print number(100)` you'd see what I mean. Python 2 allows you to compare arbitrary values to each other, even if they're not really comparable, so the `<=` doesn't fail but doesn't deliver a result that makes sense either. Python 3 would generate an error if you tried to do the same thing.